# Recursive task in Celery

Tags: python, recursion, celery

Using Celery I want to write a task like this:

```
@celery.task
def add_task():
    ....
    if(condition):
        add_task.apply_async(queue="default")
```

I know that in python, there is a maximum depth when you call a recursive function. Is this constrain applying also in celery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with that.

However, if `add_task` depends on the results of the subtask, you might run into an issue where you run out of workers, but it doesn't seem like that from your small snippet.  Technically, there is a limit to how many tasks you can queue because you will eventually run out of memory.

You're better off just trying it out to see what happens!